# High cpu loading. C++/sfml

Tags: c++, optimization, sfml

My program loads the processor by 80%. Some time ago i was have same problem with gpu, i solved it by timer. Cpu loading was about 50-60 % and now - 80 %. What i did wrong? I can't solve it problem.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
char * readFile(char * filePath, unsigned int &lengthBuffer, fstream &f) {
    f.open(filePath, ios::in | ios::app | ios::binary);
    f.seekg (0, f.end);
    lengthBuffer = f.tellg();
    f.seekg (0, f.beg);
    char * fileBuffer = new char[lengthBuffer];
    f.read(fileBuffer, lengthBuffer);
    f.close();
    return fileBuffer;
}
char * writeFile(char * fileBuffer, char * filePath, unsigned int &lengthBuffer, fstream &f, bool &fileCreated){
    filePath[23] += 1;
    f.open(filePath, ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);
    f.write(fileBuffer, lengthBuffer);
    filePath[23] -= 1;
    fileCreated = 1;
    f.close();
    return fileBuffer;
}

void removeFile(char * filePath, bool &fileCreated) {
    filePath[23] += 1;
    remove(filePath);
    filePath[23] -= 1;
    fileCreated = 0;
}
unsigned int mouse(unsigned int &funcSelector, bool &mouseLeft, sf::RenderWindow &window) {
    mouseLeft = sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left);
    sf::Vector2i mouse = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
    if (mouseLeft & mouse.y < 100) {
        funcSelector = 1 + mouse.x/100;
    }
    return funcSelector;
}
int main(){
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(500, 400), "COT++", sf::Style::Titlebar);
    sf::VertexArray points(sf::Points, 3000);
    sf::Event event;
    fstream f;
    bool mouseLeft, fileCreated = 0;
    unsigned int n = 0, funcSelector = 0, lengthBuffer = 0;
    float start = 0, now = 0, x = 0.f, y = 1.f, pos = 0.f;
    char * fileBuffer, filePath[30] = "c:/users/79994/desktop/a.exe";
    while (x < 500.f){
        points[n].position = sf::Vector2f(x + pos, y + pos);
        points[n].color = sf::Color::Green;
        x += 1.f;
        n += 1;
        if (x == 500.f & y < 100.f){
            x = 0.f;
            y += 100.f;
        }
    }
    x = 100.f, y = 1.f;
    while (x < 600.f){
        points[n].position = sf::Vector2f(x + pos, y + pos);
        points[n].color = sf::Color::Green;
        y += 1.f;
        n += 1;
        if (y > 101.f){
            x += 100.f;
            y = 1.f;
        }
    }
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if((clock()-start) > 50){
            start = clock();
            switch(funcSelector){
                case 5: window.close();
                break;
                case 1: if (lengthBuffer == 0){
                    fileBuffer = readFile(filePath, lengthBuffer, f);
                }    
                break;
                case 2: if (lengthBuffer > 0 & fileCreated == 0) {
                    writeFile(fileBuffer, filePath, lengthBuffer, f, fileCreated);
                }
                break;
                case 3: removeFile(filePath, fileCreated);  
                break;
            }
            mouse(funcSelector, mouseLeft, window);
            window.clear();
            window.draw(points);
            window.display();
        }
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

P.S.
"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details" - I think i described enough details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do. For the simple example you've given, you can use `waitEvent` instead of `pollEvent`. I recommend checking if `waitEvent` suits your needs, but it looks like it will.

However, if you insist on using `pollEvent`, read on!

Your `while(window.pollEvent(event))` loop is running at full speed 100% of the time, polling non-stop, even though it looks like your goal is to only "do work" every `50` clocks. (Clocks aren't consistently correlated to real units of measure except by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`, [which is implementation defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock)... and `std::clock` may not correlate to wall time... and `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` [might be hardcoded to 1 million when that isn't a meaningful value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)... but I digress. Your problem would exist no matter how you track time, for your code as written, though you might want some other timing mechanism.)

Here's a possible solution with minimal changes to your code. Replace:

```
    while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
        if((clock()-start) > 50){
```

with the following:

```
    while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
        const auto delta = clock() - start;
        if (delta < 50) {
          std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(
            static_cast<int>(1E6 * (50 - delta) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC)));
        } else {
```

What this does, is instead of constantly call `window.pollEvent(event)`, it'll call it, sleep for a bit if it needs to, then do some work.

There are some downsides to this approach, too, but it should get you started on how to think about the problem.

You'll need to `#include <chrono>` as well (or, you can find some other way of sleeping for the almost-right duration, if you're not using `C++11` or later).

Comment: Read the last line of the answer, it should help.

Answer (score 0):

It's more or less difficult and imprecise to try and guess just by looking at your code.
You should try to profile your code using a profiler.

PS: You also seem to have a memory leak in "readFile" and "writeFile" where you allocate a buffer but never free it again.

```
char * readFile(char * filePath, unsigned int &lengthBuffer, fstream &f) {
    // [...]
    char * fileBuffer = new char[lengthBuffer];
    // here you allocated memory on the heap, but you'll never free it.
    // [...]
    return fileBuffer;
}
```

I'd also argue not use those dynamic Char-Arrays and C-Files at all. Just use std::string and std::ostream. ostream works with more of the STL and with strings you don't have to care about its memory usage and potential memory-leaks. It cleans up after itself instead of char-arrays.

Comment: "readFile" will not called again because lengthBuffer > 0 by condition. I will analyze loaded array. Thanks for answer.